# Recursive initializer works when I add "this"?

Tags: java

This fails to compile (with an `illegal forward reference` error), as one would expect:

```
class test {
    int x = x + 42;
}
```

But this works:

```
class test {
    int x = this.x + 42;
}
```

What's going on? What gets assigned in the latter case?

Comment: How odd... (+1)

Comment: Reminds me of: while (true) { try { return; } finally { continue; } }

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Summary: Both initializers access a field that's yet to be initialized (and therefore still has the default value of zero). Since this is likely to be a programming error, the language bans some simple forms of such access. However, it does not ban more complex form.

The behaviour is compliant with the JLS, specifically [§8.3.2.3. Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3)

> The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is used only if the member is an instance (respectively `static`) field of a class or interface `C` and all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively `static`) variable initializer of C or in an instance (respectively `static`) initializer of C.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - The usage is via a simple name.
> - `C` is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.

The first example satisfies all four conditions and is therefore invalid. The second example doesn't satisfy the third condition (`this.x` is not a simple name), and is therefore OK.

The overall sequence of events is as follows:

- When an instance of a class is created, all fields are initialized to their type's default values.
- [Initializers are then run in textual order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15831155/367273) (from top to bottom).

Thus if an initializer refers to a field that appears later in the class definition (or to the field itself), it would see the default value of that other field. This is likely to be be a programming error and is therefore explicitly forbidden by §8.3.2.3.

If you circumvent §8.3.2.3 by, for example, using `this.` to forward-refer to a field, [you'll see the default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15831295/367273) (zero for `int`). Thus the following is well-defined and is guaranteed to set `x` to `42`:

```
class test {
    int x = this.x + 42;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

It is too difficult to discover and forbid all accesses to `x` during x's initialization. For example

```
int x = that().x;                |    int x = getX();
                                 |
Test that(){ return this; }      |    int getX(){ return x; }
```

The spec stops at "access by simple name" and does not try to be more comprehensive.

In another section, "Definite Assignment", the spec does the similar thing. For example

```
public class Test
{
    static final int y;
    static final int z = y;  // fail, y is not definitely assigned 
    static{ y = 1; }
}

public class Test
{
    static final int y;
    static final int z = Test.y;  // pass... because it's not a simple name
    static{ y = 1; }
}
```

Interestingly, "Definite Assignment" specifically mentions that `this.x` is equivalent to `x`

> (or, for a field, the simple name of the field qualified by this)

this clause could be added to the section quoted by NPE as well.

> - the usage is via a simple name (or a simple name qualified by this)

But in the end, it is impossible at compile time to analyze all possible usages/accesses to a field.

Comment: Do you have a view on whether `int x = this.x + 42;` has well-defined semantics?

Comment: the spec probably should forbid it as well, like "the usage is via a simple name or a simple name qualified by this"

Answer (score 1):

In the first case compiler tries to evaluate expression 'x + 42' but fails because x is not initialized.

In the second case expression 'this.x + 42' is evaluated at runtime (because of 'this' keyword), when x is already initialized and has value 0.