# Ordering of instance variable initializers

Tags: java, initialization

It seems intuitively clear that in Java, [instance variable intitializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2) are executed in the order in which they appear in the class declaration.

This certainly appears to be the case in the JDK I am using. For example, the following:

```
public class Clazz {
    int x = 42;
    int y = this.z;
    int z = this.x;
    void print() {
        System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Clazz().print();
    }
}
```

prints `42 0 42` (in other words, `y` picks up the default value of `z`).

Is this ordering actually guaranteed? I've been looking through the JLS, and can't find any explicit confirmation.

Comment: at the time `y` is assigned, `z` is still not initialized, therefore it shows `0`.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: That's exactly my intuition. The question is whether this is formally specified by the JLS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The se7 JLS covers instance variable initialization order in the [12.5 Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) section:

> ...
>   4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable
>   initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the
>   left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code
>   for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an
>   exception, then no further initializers are processed and this
>   procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise,
>   continue with step 5.
>   ...

[the JLS for Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.7) mentions in the "Classes" section:

> The static initializers and class variable initializers are  executed
>   in textual order.

Answer (score 0):

yes the variables initialisation in the class are executed in the same order. So in your second line y takes the default value o of z since z is not initialised