# why static block cannot access the static variable defined after it

Tags: java, java-8, static, static-block

I've checked [Forward References During Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) and this [the answer from @assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16635272/2361308), but still I got no answer to the *why*.

Why a static block can  assign the static variable declared after it but can **NOT** access it?

```
   class Parent {
        static {
            i = 2; // valid
            // can only assign new value to it instead of accessing it?
//            System.out.println(i); // invalid - compile-error
        }
        static int i = 0;
        static {
            i = 3; // valid
        }
    }
```

Is it due to the fact: the value is not initialized yet, so we just explicitly inhibit you from using it? or there are something related to security I don't know?

---

#### updated

this is not a duplicate of that problem which is about

> Why this doesn't happen when accessing with **class name**?

This question is about why we have this design? for what purpose?

Comment: there will be `compile error` as mentioned @Lino so you simply cannot get the bytecode

Comment: @Lino This code doesn't compile. There is no bytecode to check. Don't post meaningless guesswork here.

Comment: Yes, it is because it isn't initialized yet, which is what the error message says, isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why illegal forward reference error not shown while using static variable with class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153703/why-illegal-forward-reference-error-not-shown-while-using-static-variable-with-c)

Comment: @Lino please check the update for `duplication` issue

Comment: @Hearen Asking *why* language desicions were made are not easy-to-answer-questions. This requires quite in-depth knowledge from one of the java developers and unless Brian Goetz comes around I am not sure if anyone here can answer this

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry to post such question. But first, this is not a duplicate; second, I know this question is not simple (even as you said impossible question) and that's why add this message in the question when I start it: "There will be downvotes, but I just lost the clue in the forest." which is removed by luk2302.

Comment: @Lino Thanks for the help along the way. My idea is simple: I want to learn it & understand it. Sorry for bothering you much :) have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further reading, I think Pavel is not quite accurate in this point as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235056/why-static-block-cannot-access-the-static-variable-defined-after-it#comment-97254054) pointed out in the comment.

> we have initialized i variable twice, which is not possible, since the field is static.

As the [12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) points out

> For each class or interface C, there is a **unique initialization lock LC**. The mapping from C to LC is left to the discretion of the Java Virtual Machine implementation.

I suppose the initialization **twice** is okay to the class initializer itself as long as it's just **once** to the invoking clients.

But the demos Pavel provided still stands its position so I basically just reuse it here but with different explanation.

```
static {
       i = 2;
       j = i + 5; 
       // no one knows whether "i" here initialized properly here
}
static int i = 10;
static int j;
```

But when you use `MyClass.i` directly in `j = MyClass.i + 5`, the compiler would know it would then be okay as [8.3.3. Forward References During Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) detailed with four conditions.

> Specifically, it is a compile-time error if **all** of the following are
>   true:
>
> 1. The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears
>      textually after a use of the class variable;
> 2. **The use is a simple name** in either a class variable initializer of C
>      or a static initializer of C;
> 3. The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
> 4. C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

And there is a detailed discussion in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29153929/2361308) already.

To wind it up, I think this would be for **predictable behavior** to add these restrictions. Once again, the other official purpose pointed out in [8.3.3. Forward References During Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3).

> These restrictions are designed to catch, at compile time, circular or otherwise malformed initializations.

Answer (score 4):

Static fields are initialized **based on the order** they appear in the code.

So, when you assign a value to `i` variable you just say to the compiler: "Hey, guy, when you get to initialize this variable, set its value to...". But you can not **use** it until it's initialized because it simply does not exist yet.

**UPDATE:**

As it says in the book "The Java Language Specification" by James Gosling, Bill Joy, Guy Steele and Gilad Bracha:

> These restrictions are designed to catch, at compile time, circular or
>   otherwise malformed initializations.

Consider this:

```
static {
            i = 2;
            j = i + 5; //should it be 7 or 15?
}
static int i = 10;
static int j;
```

Should `j` variable be 7 or 15?
If it's 7, then we have initialized `i` variable twice, which is not possible, since the field is static. If it's 15 then what does `i = 2;` mean?

This code is ambiguous, so Java Specification does not allow to do that.

Comment: Provided some explanation.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I just got lost and have no idea why this is not allowed. This example does give me the clue. Thank you so much! Pavel

Comment: “*then we have initialized `i` variable twice, which is not possible, since the field is static*” ahem, why do you think that this is not possible? You can assign a variable as often as you like, unless it is **`final`**. You can easily write `static int i = 2, j = i++ + 5;    static { i += 3; }` Or you change `j = i + 5;` in your own example to `j = ClassName.i + 5;` and it works, as the variable *does* exist already.

Comment: It says so in Java specification: "At run time, the initializer is evaluated and the assignment performed exactly once, when the class is initialized". Here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3 and here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2 About referencing a variable by its full name. In this case the compiler knows exactly that the class has already been initialized This question was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153703/why-illegal-forward-reference-error-not-shown-while-using-static-variable-with-c

Answer (score 0):

The same is also applicable to the non-static members. You can assign values to them in instance initializer block but can not use them before initialization.

```
class Parent {
    {
        x = 3; // works fine
        // System.out.println(x); // gives compilation error.

    }
    int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```